# $ \sup_{x\in C}\|x\|=\sup_{x^*\in B^*}\sup_{x\in C}\langle x^*,x\rangle $

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-topology

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space, the associated dual space is denoted by $X^*$ and the usual duality between $X$ and $X^*$ by $\langle , \rangle$.  Let $B^*$ the closed unit ball of $X^*$.

Take $C$ nonempty weakly compact convex subsets of $X$. Can we say that:

$$
\sup_{x\in C}\|x\|=\sup_{x^*\in B^*}\sup_{x\in C}\langle x^*,x\rangle
$$

It is obvious that
$$
\sup_{x^*\in B^*}\sup_{x\in C}\langle x^*,x\rangle\leq \sup_{x\in C}\|x\|
$$
But for inverse inequality. $C$ should it be bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reverse inequality holds without any assumptions on $C$.

Let $x \in C$. By the Hahn-Banach theorem, there exists $x^* \in B^*$ such that $\lVert x \rVert = \langle x^*,x\rangle$. Thus
$$\lVert x \rVert \leq \sup_{y \in C} \,\langle x^*,y\rangle \leq \sup_{y^* \in B^*}\sup_{y\in C} \,\langle y^*,y\rangle.$$
Taking the supremum over $x \in C$ yields the result.

Comment: Why there existe $x^*\in B^*$ such that $\|x\|=\langle x^*,x\rangle$?

Comment: This is a consequence of the Hahn-Banach theorem. See Theorem 6.9 [here](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~mazag/functional_analysis/lecture6.pdf) for a proof.

Comment: so we can say that $\|x^*\|_*=1$

Comment: Yes you can always choose such a $x^*$.